# FileNotFound when tring to save file

Tags: java, android, copy, save

I have a strange problem. I'm trying to save a backup of my sqlite database. I've created this code

```
String DB_PATH;
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
            DB_PATH = context.getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath().replace("files", "databases") + File.separator;
        }
        else {
            DB_PATH = context.getFilesDir().getPath() + context.getPackageName() + "/databases/";
        }

    String currentDBPath = "portals.db";
    String backupDBPath = "backupname.db";
    File sd = new File(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS + "/" + backupDBPath);
    File data = new File(DB_PATH + currentDBPath);
    try {
        InputStream in = new FileInputStream(data);
        OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(sd);

        // Transfer bytes from in to out
        byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
        int len;
        while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0) {
            out.write(buf, 0, len);
        }
        in.close();
        out.close();

    } catch(Exception e) {
        int test = 1;
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

When I run this I receive FileNotFound exception. Shouldn't it create the file ? I even tried to create a dummy file still same result.

Note that I want to save that on INTERNAL memory beucase I don't have SD card in my device. What is wrong with that code ?

Comment: What is the message of the `FileNotFoundException`? Access is denied? Too many open files? Cannot find the file specified?

Comment: Before I dig deeper, do you have the permission to write to external storage in your manifest? Know that on android, writing to `/sdcard/` is not actually writing to a physical external SDCard, but the user storage that is built into the device. A physical sd cards is located at `/storage/external_SD/` or the likes. To write to either of these, you still need the External Storage permission.

Comment: Rainbolt as I wrote. I get FileNotFound exception. 
MattClark as I wrote. I want to save on INTERNAL memory. Not on external beucause I don't SD card in my device. And yes permission for SD are set

Comment: @Fixus That's the type of the exception, not the message. Inside of your catch, write `System.out.println(e.getMessage());` and add the output of that line of code to your question. There are many reasons why a `FileNotFoundException` might be thrown, and I want to know why yours was thrown.

Comment: @Rainbolt point taken :) message is: /Download/backupname.db: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

Comment: I just did a small test and `FileOutputStream.Write()` will create the file if it doesn't exist, but it won't create all of the directories leading up to it. So my next question is, does the "Download" directory exist? I see that Android devices have a /sdcard/download directory, but you said you don't have an SD card, so you probably can't write to it.

Comment: @Rainbolt Yes this directory exists on my device

Comment: Not an Android expert here, so I might be blowing smoke, but according to [this article](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal) you can only see files that your application created. So even if that directory does exist, if your application didn't create it, then your application can't see it. If you just create it yourself, does that help? (The code to do that would be `data.mkdirs();`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution.

To solve problem with my code line

```
File sd = new File(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS + "/" + backupDBPath);
```

Should look like this

```
    File sd = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS + "/" + backupDBPath);
```

Also interesting note for future. The file is saved properly but I could see it only after unplugin and plugin device. So some kind of restart was needed in terms of connection to pc